# prove that $s = {1+x,1+x+x^2,2+x+x^2}$ is a generating set of all polynomials with degree <= 2

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

prove that $S = {1+x,1+x+x^2,2+x+x^2}$ is a generating set of all polynomials with degree $\leq$ 2

lets say $b_1,b_2,b_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ if S is a generator of $P_2$ then we can express all elements of $P_2$ as linear combiantion of S then:

$${b_1(1+x)+b_2(1+x+x^2)+b_3(2+x+x^2)} = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$$

grouping common terms:
$$(b_1+b_2+2b_3)+x(b_1+b_2+2_b3)+x^2(b_2+b_3) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$$

then we have the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 &. & a_0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & .& a_1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & . & a_2
\end{bmatrix} $$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &. & a_1-a_2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & .& -a_0+a_1+a_2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & . & a_0-a_1
\end{bmatrix} $$

I don't know how to continue the proof

Comment: Please proof-read your post and correct the typographical errors (e.g., `\{` vs `{`, start each sentence with a capital letter, end each sentence with proper punctuation, use the same variable name consistently)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Write out and prove, in the standard way,  that the elements (polynomials) in $S$ are linearly independent.

Thus they span a space of dimension $3$.

Then note that the space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$ also has dimension $3$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all let's prove that the elements of $S$ are linearly independent by the classical method, taking $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ and expressing zero as a linear combination of the elements, and proving that $a_1, a_2, a_3$ must be equals to zero.

$a_1(1+x)+a_2(1+x+x^2)+a_3(2+x+x^2)=0$

$(a_1+a_2+2a_3)+(a_1+a_2+a_3)x+(a_2+a_3)x^2=0$

Then, left hand side is the null polynomial, so:

$a_1+a_2+2a_3=0$ $(1)$

$a_1+a_2+a_3=0$ $(2)$

$a_2+a_3=0$ $(3)$

$(2)-(1) \rightarrow a_3=0$

$(3)-(2) \rightarrow a_1=0$

Replacing $a_3=0$ in $(3)$ and $a_2=0$.

Then, the only solution is $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$, so they are linearly independent.

Now, take $S'=1, x, x^2$. Using the same method as above we can conclude that is a linearly independent set. In addition, every element of the space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2 can be written as $a\times 1+b\times x+c\times x^2$, so we can conclude that $S'$ is a base of this space. But $S$ is a linearly independent subset of the space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2, and has the same cardinal as $S'$ which is a base, then $S$ is a base too and generates all the space.

Answer (score 1):

So You have a system of linear equations with unknowns $b_1,b_2,b_3$ we can represent it in the form $Ax=b$,this non homogeneous system has a unique solution if $\det{A}\neq 0$... the matrix you constructed has non-zero determinant and hence given any $a_0,a_1,a_2$, we can find $b_0,b_1,b_2$ as desired.

Comment: the system is always solvable then there exists $b_0,b_1,b_2$ such that satysfyes $(b_1+b_2+2b_3)+x(b_1+b_2+2_b3)+x^2(b_2+b_3) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ is that your conclusion?

Comment: @samsamradas yes...

Answer (score 1):

There's a short cut. Note that
$$
\begin{aligned} 
1 &= (2 + x + x^2)-(1+x+x^2)\\
x &= (1+x)-1\\
x^2&= (1+x+x^2)-(1+x)
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ of the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2 can be expressed in terms of linear combinations of the given set $$\{1+x,1+x+x^2,2+x+x^2\}$$
so that set is generating.

Comment: +1. All the other answers do more work than is required (i.e. showing linear Independence).